# User Swiper.js in Astro.build

Tags: slider, swiper.js, astrojs

Please can anyone help me how I can use swiper or any other slider in astro.build?

Like we use in react.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to implement carousel as React component, [client:load](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/#hydrating-interactive-components) works as Andrés already noted.

```jsx
// src/components/MySwiper.jsx
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';

export default function MySwiper() {
  return (
    <Swiper>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  );
}
```

```html
---
// src/pages/swiper.astro
import MySwiper from '../components/MySwiper.jsx';
---
<MySwiper client:load />
```

Or if you don't mind using Swiper from CDN you can use [Client-Side Scripts](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-components/#client-side-scripts).

```js
---
// src/pages/swiper.astro
---
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<script is:inline src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script is:inline>new Swiper('.swiper')</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use swipper js, the React component set client:load for example:

`<MySlider client:load />`